# While fetching 4000 or more values from a database (postgresql) it is not possible to filter the elements. (using Reactive streams)

Tags: postgresql, spring-webflux, reactive-streams

It is necessary to filter the flow of values from the database (filtering must be performed in a reactive, non-blocking style). You need to get the incoming element, take the email field from it and validate this value. After the first correct result. Stop processing.

However. to get a valid value, you may have to process several thousand elements before you get the first suitable value.

```java
public class User {

    @Id
    Long id;

    String email;
    
    String phoneHome;
}
```

there is a search by phone number

```java
private Mono<Response> findUserByHomePhone(Response response) {

    return Mono.just(response)
            .flatMap(this::retrieveUserList);
}
```

```java
private Mono<Response> retrieveUserList (Response response) {

    String phone = retrievePhoneFromResponse (response);
  
    return Mono.from(userService.getByPhone (phone)
                    .groupBy(Customer::getId)
                    .flatMap(this::processGroupedObjects)
                    .switchOnFirst((signal, flux) -> getFirsFoundElement(signal, response)))
            .as(Log.of(log,
                    "Search by phone {}",
                    phone (response))::info);
}
```

- **userService.getByPhone (phone)** - through the *service class* (**@Transactional** is installed above it), the method defined in **ReactiveCrudRepository** is accessed, This method initiates a request to the **database**. Request of the type:

```sql
select * from users by phone = $1
```

- **.groupBy(Customer::getId)** - we iterate through the flow of elements, each element of the flow is a **User**. We perform **grouping** by **id**.
- **.flatMap(this::processGroupedObjects)**

  - processing **grouped objects**. this is where **freezes** are possible. in Debug mode, I couldn't check all the elements. since the first few thousand elements have as **email** -> **null**.
- **.switchOnFirst((signal, flux) -> getFirsFoundElement(signal, response)))** -  as soon as there is a user whose email field is filled in, we return the result.

```java
private Mono< Response > getFirsFoundElement(Signal<? extends User> signal, Response response) {

    boolean isFoundElement = signal.hasValue();

    if (isFoundElement) {
        return Mono.just(response);
    }

    return Mono.error(new Exception());
}


private Flux<User> processGroupedObjects(GroupedFlux<Long, User> group) {

    return group
            .mapNotNull(this::checkEmailOnNull);
}

private User checkEmailOnNull (User user) {

    String email = user.getEmail();

    if (Strings.isEmpty(email)){
        return null;
    }

    return user;
}
```

However, **approximately** at this point (process **Group Objects(GroupedFlux<Lang, User> group**)) - a **freezes** occurs, I do not observe errors in the console.

The number of source elements in the database is from **4 000** to **25 000** (the algorithm worked for **3000**).

I found this:
[GroupedFlux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_grouping_with_fluxgroupedfluxt)

> Grouping is best suited for when you have a medium to low number of
> groups. The groups must also imperatively be consumed (such as by a
> flatMap) so that groupBy continues fetching data from upstream and
> feeding more groups. Sometimes, these two constraints multiply and
> lead to hangs, such as when you have a high cardinality and the
> concurrency of the flatMap consuming the groups is too low.

however, it is not clear to me what was meant in the documentation, although I think my case is described here, but I am not sure about it.

Мaybe anyone has any ideas why **freezes** occur, how it could be fixed?

Comment: Is it possible that you get just to many _group_ subscriptions that consume all scheduler resources? I mean, how many groups you usually have for such a request?

Comment: I have 8000 objects, each with a unique id, since grouping by id, I believe that each object = a group, that is, a group of 1 object, means 8000 groups (there may be more records)

Comment: From my experience that could cause a problem. Probably because each new group is a new subscriber, so when there are thousands of them they may just stuck. Though I'm not sure why. I suggest to rewrite the code without using the grouping

Comment: I do not know how else to build a filter in a reactive stack. I need to filter the flow of elements and check the email field in a non-blocking style, and if I find the first positive element, then I just return it, if I don't find any, empty is returned.

Comment: What is the goal of that filter? Just find a first user with an email across all? Like any user with an email? What's the purpose of the grouping here?

Comment: so in the description above it is indicated that you need to find a user with a valid email, and there may be 8000 records in front of him, where the email does not correspond to the correct format.

Comment: Yes, that's what I see and it seems that any user with a correct email would suffice. So no grouping is needed. Do I miss anything?

Comment: This is true. But, for example, 8000 records with the wrong email address, 8001 with the correct one. Thus, I have to process a stream of 8000 elements in order to find the entry 8001 in the order of the queue where the correct email is.  At the same time, it is necessary to avoid using regular expressions, both at the database level.

Comment: Yes, you have to check all the 8001 items. It doesn't matter which algorithm you use, there is no magic solution if your original data is already organized in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out, grouping doesn't work for a flow with many groups. So I suggest avoiding the groups at all.

As your goal is just to find any user with an email it's simple:

```
userService.getByPhone (phone)
  .filter((user) -> user.getEmail() != null)
  .next()
```

If you want to get emails for all users you don't need a `groupBy` too, just use `distinct`:

```
userService.getByPhone (phone)
  .filter((user) -> user.getEmail() != null)
  .distinct((user) -> user.getId())
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm checking your advice.There can be like this "", and so "mail..com " , and so "@c.com " , and you need to find the first valid email, this will be the record you are looking for, but not just a null check.

Comment: .next() or .distinct() - not suitable in this case, you forgot that : Mono.from ( userService.getByPhone (phone) )

Comment: Well, I'm sure you understand how to replace `!= null` with mode sophisticated check, because I don't know all the requirement for the email and they are irrelevant to the solution. Same for `Mono.from`. I'm giving you an example that would solve you general problem and it should be easy to adapt for your actual needs.

Answer (score 0):

I organized the filter like this :

```java
 private Mono<Response> filterUsersByEmail(Response response) {

        String phone = retrieveMobilePhoneFromResponse(response);

       return userService
                .findByMobilePhone(phone)
                .filter(user -> isaBoolean(user))
                .next()
                .switchIfEmpty(
                        Mono.defer(() -> Mono.error(
                        new Exception())
                )
                )
               .flatMap(user -> Mono.just(response));

}

 private static boolean isaBoolean(User user) {

        String email = user.getEmail();
        boolean b = !Strings.isEmpty(email);
        return b;
    }
```